# how to avoid error Subquery returns more than 1 row in sqlyog

Tags: mysql

Here i want to return all the rows in my result, But after executing the query it giving the error.

```
Error Code : 1242    Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Thank you in advance...!

```
BEGIN

    DECLARE TODAYS DATE;
    DECLARE RESULTDAYS DATE;
    DECLARE ISSUEDAYS DATE;
    DECLARE DAYS INT;

    SET TODAYS=CURDATE();
    SET ISSUEDAYS= (SELECT issue_date FROM bookstore.issue_book WHERE 
    return_date IS NULL AND status = 0);

    SET DAYS=(TODAYS-ISSUEDAYS);    
    SELECT DAYS;

   END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: `issue_book`  have more records in this condition. Did you check

Comment: yes it having the 20 records.. i want the DAYS=todays-issuedays will give result of this 20 records

Comment: Do You know `Cursor`?

Comment: yes.....but not implemented yet... shall i use it..?

Comment: how many records do you get when setting the ISSUEDAYS variable?

Comment: i want 20 records....but it giving the above error

Comment: i am new ....for mysql and stored procedure